# Wrapping FUSE from Go

Tags: c, go, fuse

I'm playing around with wrapping FUSE with Go. However I've come stuck with how to deal with `struct fuse_operations`. I can't seem to expose the operations struct by declaring `type Operations C.struct_fuse_operations` as the members are lower case, and my pure-Go sources would have to use C-hackery to set the members anyway. My first error in this case is "can't set getattr" in what looks to be the Go equivalent of a default copy constructor. My next attempt is to expose an interface that expects `GetAttr`, `ReadLink` etc, and then generate `C.struct_fuse_operations` and bind the function pointers to closures that call the given interface.

This is what I've got (explanation continues after code):

```
package fuse

// #include <fuse.h>
// #include <stdlib.h>
import "C"

import (
    //"fmt"
    "os"
    "unsafe"
)

type Operations interface {
    GetAttr(string, *os.FileInfo) int
}

func Main(args []string, ops Operations) int {
    argv := make([]*C.char, len(args) + 1)
    for i, s := range args {
        p := C.CString(s)
        defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(p))
        argv[i] = p
    }
    cop := new(C.struct_fuse_operations)
    cop.getattr = func(*C.char, *C.struct_stat) int {}
    argc := C.int(len(args))
    return int(C.fuse_main_real(argc, &argv[0], cop, C.size_t(unsafe.Sizeof(cop)), nil))
}

package main

import (
    "fmt"
 "fuse"
    "os"
)

type CpfsOps struct {
    a int
}

func (me *CpfsOps) GetAttr(string, *os.FileInfo) int {
    return -1;
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(os.Args)
    ops := &CpfsOps{}
    fmt.Println("fuse main returned", fuse.Main(os.Args, ops))
}
```

This gives the following error:

```
fuse.go:21[fuse.cgo1.go:23]: cannot use func literal (type func(*_Ctype_char, *_Ctype_struct_stat) int) as type *[0]uint8 in assignment
```

I'm not sure what to pass to these members of `C.struct_fuse_operations`, and I've seen mention in a few places it's not possible to call from C back into Go code.

If it is possible, what should I do? How can I provide the "default" values for interface functions that acts as though the corresponding `C.struct_fuse_operations` member is set to NULL?

Comment: I'd like to award the bounty to an answer that address my interface concerns, not specifically to FUSE.

Answer (score 1):

http://cheesesun.blogspot.com/2010/04/callbacks-in-cgo.html describes a general - if somewhat convoluted - technique. http://groups.google.com/group/golang-nuts/browse_thread/thread/abd0e30dafdbf297?tvc=2&pli=1 describes the problem.

I suspect that if you want to handle the function pointers as anything other than uintptrs, you'll have to hack on cgo.